# best way to group adjacent duplicate values into an array

Tags: javascript, loops, lodash

I'm having an array `roomList` it have some values like

```
let roomList=[
  {value:1,type:2},{value:2,type:2},{value:3,type:2},{value:4,type:3}, 
  {value:5,type:4},{value:6,type:4},{value:7,type:6},{value:8,type:6}, 
  {value:9,type:1},{value:10,type:8},{value:11,type:8},{value:12,type:8}
];
```

What I'm trying to do is push all the `roomList[i].value` into another array **(roomList[i].value will be unique)**. But some how I'm not able to get all the desired objects.

my code goes like this

```
let adjacentRoomId=[];

for(let i=0;i<roomList.length;i++){
 for(let j=i+1;j<roomList.length;j++){
    if(roomList[i].type===roomList[j].type){
     adjacentRoomId.push(roomList[i].value);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid duplication in `adjascentRoomId` array also.
I'm also using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10)

Comment: What's the result you're expecting for this input?

Comment: I'm expecting something like this **adjascentRoomId=[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11,12]**

Comment: what qualifies and *adjacent* room?

Comment: Are you trying to filter an array to only have duplicate values, removing unique ones?

Comment: @NinaScholz  adjacent rooms are those rooms which are of same type and next to each other of same type 
**Eg: Room No: 1,2,3 are adjacent were as Room No:4 doesn't have one next to it same type**

Comment: @ProfessorAllman yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by `type`.

```js
let roomList = [{ value: 1, type: 2 }, { value: 2, type: 2 }, { value: 3, type: 2 }, { value: 4, type: 3 }, { value: 5, type: 4 }, { value: 6, type: 4 }, { value: 7, type: 6 }, { value: 8, type: 6 }, { value: 9, type: 1 }, { value: 10, type: 8 }, { value: 11, type: 8 }, { value: 12, type: 8 }],
    result = Array.from(roomList.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.type, (m.get(o.type) || []).concat(o)), new Map).values());
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```js
let roomList = [{ value: 1, type: 2 }, { value: 2, type: 2 }, { value: 3, type: 2 }, { value: 4, type: 3 }, { value: 5, type: 4 }, { value: 6, type: 4 }, { value: 7, type: 6 }, { value: 8, type: 6 }, { value: 9, type: 1 }, { value: 10, type: 8 }, { value: 11, type: 8 }, { value: 12, type: 8 }],
    result = _(roomList)
        .groupBy('type')
        .map((values, type) => ({ type, values: _.map(values, 'value') }))
        .value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an ES6 `Set` to take care of the unique issue. Then it is a reduce/find combination and it can be one-liner:

```js
let roomList=[
  {value:1,type:2},{value:2,type:2},{value:3,type:2},{value:4,type:3}, 
  {value:5,type:4},{value:6,type:4},{value:7,type:6},{value:8,type:6}, 
  {value:9,type:1},{value:10,type:8},{value:11,type:8},{value:12,type:8}
];

var result = _.reduce(roomList, (r,c,i,a) => 
_.find(a, x => x.type == c.type && x.value != c.value) ? r.add(c.value) : r, new Set)

console.log(Array.from(result))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just through main array and check the elements in second array that you are generating.

If element exists in second array , just don't insert it to the second array.

In output, `{value:12,type:8},{value:9,type:1}` will not repeat and only comes once.

```js
var x = roomList=[
  {value:1,type:2},{value:2,type:2},{value:3,type:2},{value:4,type:3}, 
  {value:5,type:4},{value:6,type:4},{value:7,type:6},{value:8,type:6}, 
  {value:9,type:1},{value:10,type:8},{value:11,type:8},{value:12,type:8},{value:12,type:8},{value:9,type:1}
];

var n = [];

x.forEach(function(e){
  var isExists = false; 
 n.forEach(function(ne){
  if(ne == e.value){
   isExists = true;
  }
 });
 if(!isExists){
  n.push(e.value);
 }
});

console.log(n.join(","));

console.log(n);
```